# How to filter data from a connection string in php

Tags: php, database-connection

I have the following connection string and have this standard syntax always.
`mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mydb`
Is there an easy way to filter the information(host, port,dbname) to a php variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.parse-str.php) and [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php) to do the trick.

```
<?php
$str='mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mydb';
parse_str(str_replace(';','&',$str),$arr);
print_r($arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [mysql:host] => localhost
    [port] => 3306
    [dbname] => mydb
)
```